# HUE Query Left Join no Results

Tags: hiveql, hue

I run a hivesql in Hue 3.10.0 and return no results, Hive SQL like this:

```
select t1.id
      ,t2.id 
from ( 
    select id from table1 where date = '20181121' and type = 'a'
    ) t1
left join(
    select id from table1 where date = '20181121' and type = 'b' and
   ) t2
on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Then I run sunquery t1:

```
select id from table1 where date = '20181121' and type = 'a';
```

and it retrun 437 rows,

I try add "group by" after subquery t1,and query like this:

```
select t1.id
      ,t2.id 
from ( 
    select id from table1 where date = '20181121' and type = 'a' group by id
    ) t1
left join(
    select id from table1 where date = '20181121' and type = 'b' and
   ) t2
on t1.id = t2.id;
```

it also returns 437 rows;

Then I change table1 to another table, which return a normal result, I use another tool "superset" to run the first query above, it also returns 437 rows, So I doubt "Hue" caused this problem, But I am puzzled why it happened?

Answer (score 0):

It could be hue is causing the issue .can you try using on **trim(t1.id) = trim(t2.id)**

apply trim on both sides and try it

Comment: I try using `on trim(t1.id) = trim(t2.id)` and `on bigint(t1.id) = bigint(t2.id)`, both return no results.

Comment: ok..can you try creating external table if you are using now internal table.suppose if you are using external table ..save the data in the another location other than currently wherever you saved it and try to load the data